# Why does React recommend controlled input? doesn't it trigger re-render too often?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, user-input

Based on the example code from https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Every time I type or remove a character in the input textbox, `handleChange` updates the component state and triggers a re-render. And this seems to be the normal approach in React. Isn't this design triggering re-render way too often?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/markerikson/d71cfc81687f11609d2559e8daee10cc might shed some light

Comment: I think in short, no, it doesn't trigger a re-render too often. Why? Because that's what React's render logic was designed to do from the beginning, and they spent a large amount of time researching and making sure that rendering will be quick. And per the docs, part of their investigation yielded that making React elements immutable and only applying DOM updates to what actually changed allowed the performance to still meet the SLA.